# symfony2 still using MYSQL instead of POSTGRESQL

Tags: php, symfony

my parameters.ini file:

```
; These parameters can be imported into other config files
; by enclosing the key with % (like %database_user%)
; Comments start with ';', as in php.ini
[parameters]
    database_driver="pdo_pgsql"
    database_host="localhost"
    database_port=""
    database_name="mydbname"
    database_user="postgres"
    database_password="somepassword"
    mailer_transport="smtp"
    mailer_host="localhost"
    mailer_user=""
    mailer_password=""
    locale="en"
    secret="ffdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfdf"
```

my config.yml file is as follows:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
```

I also did:

```
php bin/vendors update
php app/console assets:install web
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
chmod 777 -R app/cache app/logs
```

However when I do the schema:create, I get:

```
[PDOException]                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists  

doctrine:schema:create [--dump-sql] [--em[="..."]]
```

It appears it is still trying to create stuff in the MYSQL database since that has the users table already. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What makes it appear this way? PDO works with PostgreSQL I believe. Does that table not exist in your PG db?